# Cannot display comments with CakePHP Comments Plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, comments, cakephp-1.3

I have the [CakePHP Comments Plugin](http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_comments_plugin) set-up correctly, I believe.  I've followed the poorly-written instructions [[here]](https://github.com/CakeDC/comments/blob/master/readme.md) to the point where it's requiring me to login to add a comment.  When I click "add a comment", it gives me the title and body form fields.

It's even submitting and saving the data just fine.  Then, the data comes across when I `debug($article);` - I see the comment(s) for that article in the data.

But - the only thing that appears when I have this in my view:

```
<? $commentWidget->options(array('allowAnonymousComment' => false));?>
<? echo $commentWidget->display();?>
```

Is the "Add a comment" button.

How do I display the comments?  The plugin has views for index, edit, view...etc all seem to be laid out ok and for me to use, but... I tried a straight include, and it's missing lots of variables..etc, so - assume there's some kind of method or something to display the comments, like... `echo $commentWidget->comments;` or something?

**UPDATE:**

When I `debug($result)`; from `comment_widget.php`, I still just get an "Add comment" link (so there are two on the page now - one from the actual `->display()` and one from my new debug.

Below is what I'm getting when I `debug($article);` from my articles_controller.php.
I built the table myself, based on a few things I found online - and it appears to be populating (mostly) - maybe I did something wrong w/ the db setup?

```
[Comment] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [title] => dave test 2
                [created] => 2011-07-10 20:28:31
                [modified] => 2011-07-10 20:28:31
                [user_id] => 67
                [foreign_key] => 683
                [approved] => 1
                [slug] => dave_test_2
                [body] => test
                [rght] => 2
                [model] => Article
                [is_spam] => 
                [lft] => 1
                [parent_id] => 0
                [author_name] => 
                [author_url] => 
                [author_email] => 
                [language] => en-us
                [comment_type] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
                [title] => blah blah blah 6523dkaljlkfsjdsfaljsd
                [created] => 2011-07-10 21:33:43
                [modified] => 2011-07-10 21:33:43
                [user_id] => 67
                [foreign_key] => 683
                ...
```

Comment: `echo $commentWidget->display()`; should work; the method returns `$result`. Take a look at `views/helpers/comment_widget.php` and do a `debug($result);`. Does any comment data get returned?

Comment: @Ross - updated my question w/ some more details including the fact that "debug($result)" only gets me another "Add comment" button.  Think maybe it's something to do w/ my table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the table structure per the schema.php (plugins/comments/config/schema/schema.php) making sure to use their default values.  In my case, I left out the default values of 'comment' for `comment_type`, and 'clean' for the default of `is_spam`.

Fixing both of these makes it so the comments now appear correctly!  They're ugly with no CSS, so - any suggestions on that is more than welcome, but... they work!